# cassandraunit crashes immediately

Tags: scala, unit-testing, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I am trying to run cassandra unit tests on a small vanilla ubuntu 12 machine, but the test or the repl crash immediately without giving me any information. When I try it in the repl I get the following:

```
scala> org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra()
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
16:35:47,837 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
16:35:47,837 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
16:35:47,837 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/root/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/jars/play_2.10-2.3.6.jar!/logback.xml]
16:35:47,838 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
16:35:47,838 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/root/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/jars/play_2.10-2.3.6.jar!/logback.xml]
16:35:47,838 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/root/.ivy2/cache/com.websudos/phantom-test_2.10/jars/phantom-test_2.10-1.4.0.jar!/logback.xml]
16:35:47,854 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@5fe21ec9 - URL [jar:file:/root/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/jars/play_2.10-2.3.6.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
16:35:47,974 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
16:35:47,981 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
16:35:47,989 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
16:35:48,015 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
16:35:48,247 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
16:35:48,247 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
16:35:48,247 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
16:35:48,248 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@76534f4c - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
user@ubuntu:~/test$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I need >4GB of ram for the unit test. Starting with `env JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx5G" sbt test` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

from the first glance the problem seems to be multple SLF4J binding. You have multiple jars with slf4j logger in it.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-    1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

Remove any one of them and try again.

You could refer  :http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation